# Uncaught TypeError: View is not a constructor

Tags: backbone.js

I am stuck with familiar issue but I am unable to resolve it on my own. So Please help me to get rid out from this issue.

My view code:

```js
var LayoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('resources/html/layout.html', function(data) {
      self.template = _.template(data);
      self.render();
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(self.el).html(self.template(self.model.toJSON()));
  }
});
```

My rendering code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var LayoutView= new LayoutView({
        el:'#wrapper',
        model:{}
    });
});
```

My exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: LayoutView is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var layoutView= new LayoutView({
   //--^---this
    el:'#wrapper',
    model:{}
   });
});
```

Because the local variable declaration with same name is hiding the original constructor.